# Cannot assign value retrieved from api inside useState

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I want to update the value of firmDetail when there is a change in the value of input fields. To do so, I am fetching data from API and trying to assign the retrieved value from API to firmDetail in useState. But due to delays in retrieving data from API causing issues of null value in firmProfile. Here is my code:

```
const UseApiFetch = (url) => {
    const[data, setData]= useState(null);
    const[isPending, setPending]= useState(true);
    const[error, setError]= useState(null);

    useEffect( async ()=>{
        await axios.get(url).then(
            response =>{
                if(!response.status=== "200"){
                    throw error('error while fetching data');
                }
                setData(response.data);
                setPending(false);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error => {
                setPending(false);
                setError(error.message);
            })
            )
    }, [url]);
    return{data, isPending, error}
}

const { data: firmProfile, isPending, error } = UseApiFetch(constants.FIRM_PROFILE_URI);
const[firmDetail, setFirmDetail]= useState({
    firmName:"",
    firmEmail:"",
    firmPhone:"",
    firmUrl:"",
    pDate:"",
    cRename:""
})
useEffect(()=>{
    setFirmDetail({
        ...firmDetail,
        firmName: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmName,
        firmEmail: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionEmail,
        firmPhone: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionPhone,
        firmUrl: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmURL,
        pDate: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.purchaseDate,
        cRename: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.caseRename
    })
}, [firmDetail])
// if(firmProfile){
//     firmDetail.firmName = firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmName;
//     firmDetail.firmEmail=firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionEmail;
//     firmDetail.firmPhone=firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionPhone;
//     firmDetail.firmUrl=firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmURL;
//     firmDetail.pDate=firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.purchaseDate;
//     firmDetail.cRename=firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.caseRename;
// }
function handleChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    setFirmDetail({
        ...firmDetail,
        [evt.target.name]: value
    });
}
return (
    <div className="content">
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
        {isPending &&
            <div><Loader /></div>
        }
        <div className="firmDetail">
        { firmProfile &&
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <CCard>
                    <CCardHeader>
                        Firm
                        <small> Profile</small>
                    </CCardHeader>
                    <CCardBody>
                        <CFormGroup>
                            <CLabel htmlFor="name">Firm Name:</CLabel>
                            <CInput id="firmName" name="firmName" defaultValue={firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmName} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>
                        </CFormGroup>
                        <CFormGroup>
                            <CLabel htmlFor="email">Contact Email:</CLabel>
                            <CInput id="firmEmail" name="firmEmail" type="email" defaultValue={firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionEmail} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>
                        </CFormGroup>
                        <CFormGroup>
                            <CLabel htmlFor="phone">Contact Phone:</CLabel>
                            <CInput id="firmPhone" name="firmPhone"  defaultValue={firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionPhone} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>
                        </CFormGroup>
                        <CFormGroup>
                            <CLabel htmlFor="">Firm Url:</CLabel>
                            <CInput id="firmUrl" name="firmUrl" defaultValue={firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmURL} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>
                        </CFormGroup>
                        <CFormGroup>
                            <CLabel htmlFor="date">Purchase Date:</CLabel>
                            <CInput id="date" name="pDate" defaultValue={firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.purchaseDate} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>
                        </CFormGroup>
                        <CFormGroup>
                            <CLabel htmlFor="case">Case Rename</CLabel>
                            <CInput id="caseRename" name="cRename" defaultValue={firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.caseRename} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}/>
                        </CFormGroup>
                        <Row className="float-right">
                            <Button variant="success pull-right" className="float-right">Update</Button>
                        </Row>
                    </CCardBody>
                </CCard>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firmDetail` can't be a dependency for the effect that unconditionally calls `setFirmDetail` as this will create a render loop. I suspect you meant to use the `firmProfile` data response from the `UseApiFetch` hook.

The `useEffect` hook will run on the initial render cycle, likely well before the GET request resolves. You should account for the possibly null `firmProfile`  value by checking if it exists *before* attempting to access nested properties. Only if it is truthy/defined should you actually enqueue a state update.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  firmProfile && setFirmDetail({
    firmName: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmName,
    firmEmail: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionEmail,
    firmPhone: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.ltbDecisionPhone,
    firmUrl: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.firmURL,
    pDate: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.purchaseDate,
    cRename: firmProfile.firmSubscriptionDetail.caseRename,
  })
}, [firmProfile]);
```

Render from the `firmDetail` state in your JSX

```
{!isPending &&
  <div className="col-lg-6">
    <CCard>
      <CCardHeader>
        Firm
        <small> Profile</small>
      </CCardHeader>
      <CCardBody>
        <CFormGroup>
          <CLabel htmlFor="name">Firm Name:</CLabel>
          <CInput
            id="firmName"
            name="firmName"
            value={firmDetail.firmName} // <-- controlled input
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </CFormGroup>
        ...
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. but can you tell me why should i prefer firmDetail to render instead firmProfile. isn't both use are same?

Comment: @Sujan It was mostly a hunch based on context. You weren't using the `firmDetail` state anywhere but you were updating it from the values initial received from `firmProfile`. Though now I'm looking at your code you appear to mix parts of controlled and uncontrolled inputs by using the `defaultValue` attribute ***and*** an `onChange` handler. If you want fully controlled inputs then you should use the `value` attribute, if you want fully uncontrolled inputs then you should use `defaultValue` and wait to render the inputs until `firmProfile` has been populated.